# Can the Devel Generate module generate content for all possible permutations and combinations?

Tags: testing, debugging

I love the [Devel Generate](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module as it helps me to create test content very quickly. Random content that the module generates is sufficient most of the times.

But at times I would like to have content for all the permutations and combinations. For example let us say that a content type has three optional fields. So in total I would like to have 8 nodes of that type created that cover all the permutations.

Is this something that can be achieved with the Devel module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such feature in the Devel Generate module.

Therefor, as an alternative, I recommend to use a (rather basic) custom module for creating such nodes (so without using Devel Generate).

The article about [How to programmatically create nodes, comments and taxonomies in Drupal 7](http://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-in-drupal-7/) contains great example of how to do so. Here is a summary of that article (about how to programmatically create a node):

> - Initialize a node object
> - Add body field
> - Add custom fields
> - Add file / image field
> - Add a term to a node
> - Save a node

You probably don't need the "add file" and "add term", and simply have to repeat the "add custom fields" a few times (for each of your 3 fields), and then "you" are in full control of which permutations/combinations you actually want.